how to make an image inside of a text in flutter
I'm trying to achieve a text effect in Flutter where the letters appear to have an image, similar to the image attached. In this example, the word "Hawaii" has palm trees image inside of it.
Is there a way to accomplish this effect in Flutter?
the only thing I tried was adding a png image with transparent letters on top of the image using stack...which was of course not the best practice 

it calls as image masking. you can achieve what you want to do with following article:
https://medium.com/@saranafisa200/flutters-image-magic-creating-custom-shapes-and-masks-58fb8f6211fa
if you want to just focus text image masking:
https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=va6smNoyqMY
